# Method not found: 'Boolean Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.get_EnableHttpCache()'

Tags: solr, sitecore-api, upgrade

After upgrading from `Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.1`, which updated the Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider to v4.0.0.0, the code compiles fine but we get the following when trying to access the site:

Server Error in '/' Application.

**Method not found:** `Boolean Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.get_EnableHttpCache()`.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

`System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.get_EnableHttpCache()'`.

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.get_EnableHttpCache()'.]
   Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration.SolrStartup.Initialize() +0
   Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider.Process(PipelineArgs args) +110
   (Object , Object ) +9
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +215
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +1184
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +581
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: 'Boolean Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.get_EnableHttpCache()'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +714
```

When looking at the Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider in object viewer, I do not even see `SolrContentSearchManager` much less `get_EnableHttpCache()` method.

Comment: I see Sitecore.Support namespace in Stack Trace. Have you by any chance left out old patch from Sitecore in your solution? `Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration.SolrStartup.Initialize()` and `Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider.Process` . Try to remove it

Comment: Doh!!  How the hades did I miss that.  Spot on Peter.  Excluded the two support config files that referenced the missing method that no longer exists in 9.1 and we got passed this particular issue.  Now on to the dozens of other issues...lol.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see in Stack Trace. THis means that you are referencing some pipelines coming from `Sitecore.Support` namespace which means that you have still some old support tickets added into solution.

I can see these references:

1.Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration.SolrStartup.Initialize()
    2.Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider.Process

Remove them to fix these issues.